# A template for communications in statistics journal

Tags: templates, article, journal

'Statistica' journal provides Latex template for a publication. 'Communications in Statistics' only provides some guide.

Is there somewhere a database of latex templates useful for publishing in journals?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The first question you have to answer is if the journal would accept an LaTeX document or if they want a pdf file or a word document or etc. Usually if a journal does not offer a LaTeX template the do not accept LaTeX documents ... Please ask the journal!

Comment: Most journals will provide the template via their website, if available. Overleaf has a large number of known templates, which are usually up to date, see https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates